# Unity 5.2.2 changing Visual Studio back to MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Is there any way to change default script editor in unity to MonoDevelop? Using Visual Studio is very complicated and slow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open Unity, select a project then go to the top menu bar.
2. Go to Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools -> External Script Editor.
3. Then click the drop down menu and select MonoDevelop (built-in).

Comment: I don't have the "MonoDevelop (built-in)" in my dropdown. And using unity with VS Code is not working for me...